# VB.net: How do I "refresh" my comboBox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox that is populated by a database table I have. In my Load event for my form I have it populated by...

```
Me.BusinessTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BillingdbDataSet.Business)
```

My problem is whenever I "add", "edit", or "delete" a business I have stored I can't find a way to update the combobox I have.  Whenever I exit and reopen my program and I can see the changes but was hoping someone could inform me on how to have it updated after a change has happened.

Comment: Could you not put the Adapter.Fill code into a function and recall that whenever to want a refresh.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I do "Add" and "Edit" these launch an additional form and then after that it goes back to my combobox form.    I tried your suggestion also on my "Delete" button since it stays on the same form and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you need something that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

MSDN

> You can enumerate over any collection
>   that implements the IEnumerable
>   interface. However, to set up dynamic
>   bindings so that insertions or
>   deletions in the collection update the
>   UI automatically, the collection must
>   implement the INotifyCollectionChanged
>   interface. This interface exposes the
>   CollectionChanged event, an event that
>   should be raised whenever the
>   underlying collection changes.

You can refresh it manually, but the ideal situation is the bind to an observable collection class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx  HTH

Wade

Comment: I've been looking it over, but I guess since I'm still fairly new to vb I haven't been able to get it to work.  Might anyone have some example/pseudo code?  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253843/simple-datagridview-refresh-questionThis looks like they're doing what I'm wanting, but to a datagridview instead of a combobox. I don't actually create a List like they have there however. My combobox is populated by my BindingSource.  Does the bindingsource provide a list i can access?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using datasets you can use the dataview class which raises events when the underlying dataset is changed. Then you could either look into data binding them to the combo-box or write your own update code and put that in an event handler for the event raised when the list changes.