# How can I refresh c# dataGridView after update ?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView when I click on any row a form is opened to update the row data, but after ending updates the updating form is closed but the dataGridView data is not updated

How can i do that ?

Comment: dataGridView1.Refresh();

Comment: Refresh(); is graphics refresh, not data, I made the same mistake! Summary:
Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

Comment: @amer: You should accept some answers to your questions...

Answer (score 55):

`BindingSource` is the only way without going for a 3rd party ORM, it may seem long winded at first but the benefits of one update method on the `BindingSource` are so helpful.

If your source is say for example a list of user strings

```
List<string> users = GetUsers();
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = users;
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

then when your done editing just update your data object whether that be a `DataTable` or List of user strings like here and `ResetBindings` on the `BindingSource`;

```
users = GetUsers(); //Update your data object
source.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: hm, coming over from "simple DataGridView refresh question", this ResetBinding() call still doesn't work with my simple test project ;) Can you give an actual, buildable, working example of this doing the refresh properly?

Comment: ResetBindings seems to work only with .net types. I think if you use a custom collection you need to implement the IBindingList interface, but i haven't tried that yet.

Comment: What do you mean by custom collection?

Comment: Haven't tried per @EdSykes `IBindingList` suggestion, but this does *not* work with `BindingList<T>` either unfortunately.

Comment: I thought that converting all my dataGrids would be painful, but is wasnt. Thank you.:)

Answer (score 41):

Rebind your DatagridView to the source.

```
DataGridView dg1 = new DataGridView();
dg1.DataSource = src1;

// Update Data in src1

dg1.DataSource = null;
dg1.DataSource = src1;
```

Comment: This is just an example, you only want the bottom two rows, and you want them after an update. So imagine on the parent, on the child closing event.

Comment: This is how I used to do it and it does work fine but I found having a  'BindingSource' with that one 'ResetBindings' method (as per my answer) superb!

Comment: @Ian: it might be worth updating your example and mentioning that if one nulls out the DataSource property, then they lose the schema (columns). It's usually better to set it to typeof(ElementType), where ElementType is the type of bound rows.

Comment: although it works but you have to resetting some properties of your datagridview such as column header text, column size and visibility of some column such as id and ...

Answer (score 7):

I know thats an old topic but i suddenly found the best way of doing it and it does not require nullifying the datasource and reassigning it.
Just use a  BindingList instead of a List.

for example:

```
//declare your list
private BindingList<myclass> mMyList = new BindingList<myclass>();

//then bind it to your datagrid, i usually do it on the Load event
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dgMyDatagrig.DataSource = mMyList;
}

//start populating your list 
private void addItem(mycclass item)
{
    mMylist.add(item);

//the datagrid will show automatically the new added/updated items, no need to do anything else

}
```

Comment: this way it doesn't scroll to top every time new item added

Comment: This works but then you need to Invoke the Add() operation because of cross thread gui update

Comment: Fantastic, I had been using the Binding Source in the answer above - but the lack of auto-scrolling back to the top with the BindingList is a big plus in my application. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I know i am late to the party but hope this helps someone who will do the same with Class binding

```
var newEntry = new MyClassObject();

var bindingSource = dataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource;
var myClassObjects = bindingSource.DataSource as List<MyClassObject>;
myClassObjects.Add(newEntry);
bindingSource.DataSource = myClassObjects;

dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
dataGridView.Update();
dataGridView.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the DataGridView's `Invalidate()` function.  However, that will refresh the entire DataGridView.  If you want to refresh a particular row, you use `dgv.InvalidateRow(rowIndex)`. If you want to refresh a particular cell, you can use `dgv.InvalidateCell(columnIndex, rowIndex)`.  This is of course assuming you're using a binding source or data source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataGridView refresh method. But... in a lot of cases you have to refresh the DataGridView from methods running on a different thread than the one where the DataGridView is running. In order to do that you should implement the following method and call it rather than directly typing DataGridView.Refresh():

```
    private void RefreshGridView()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                RefreshGridView();
            });
        }
        else
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has really been solved or not... but by looking at all the other answers, nothing seems quite clear. The best way I found to do this is to put the same code, that was used to populate your `datagridview` into a method and pass it your form's `datagridview`, as so:

```
public void ConnectAndPopulateDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
{ }
```

The code within the method is the exact same as the code used to populate the `datagirdview` originally, except for the `datagridview` name changing to whatever you called it in your method.

Now this method is called in your parent form.

The child form is launched via a `.ShowDialog()` then the method is called after so that it is called right after the child for is closed... as so:

```
ChildForm.ShowDialog();

ConnectAndPopulateDataGridView(dataGridView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/reflect-data-source-updates-in-a-wf-control-with-the-bindingsource?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)  that demonstrates how to reset the bindings correctly, using `BindingSource.ResetBindings`.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to redefine the **DataSource**. So if you have for example DataGridView's DataSource that contains a, b, i c:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = a, b, c
```

And suddenly you update the DataSource so you have just a and b, you would need to redefine your DataSource:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = a, b
```

I hope you find this useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SqlDataAdapter to update the DataGridView

```
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table", conn))
            {
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 ad.Fill(dt);
               dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```