# Edit in datagridview successful, but it does not update the certain column

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i already can edit data in the database. But i am having a problem, when i edit and update `Quantity` column in the datagridview, it supposed to update the `Total` column in datagridview based on `Quantity * SubTotal` , but it is update only the `Quantity` column, not Price.

Where do i did wrong?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the rows "1", the `Quantity` is 100 and the `SubTotal` is 10000, so the `Total` will be 1000000. But in the rows "2", the `Quantity` before i edit in the datagridview, the Quantity is `100` and also the `Total` is 2000000, when i change the `Quantity` to the 500, the `Total` still 2000000, the `Total` supposed to be 10000000.

Where do i did wrong?

Here is the code (i post the code as necessary as needed):

```
private void Updated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable _dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            if (_dt.DefaultView.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
                string productCode = Convert.ToString(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["ProductCode"]);
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["Quantity"]);
                int price = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["SubTotal"]);
                int _price = Convert.ToInt32(_dt.DefaultView[rowNum]["Total"]);

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string _commandSelect = "SELECT [Quantity], [SubTotal], [Total] FROM [TransRecord] WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";
                    string commandUpdate = "UPDATE [Record] SET [Quantity] = @Quantity, [SubTotal] = @SubTotal, [Total] = @Total WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";
                    string _commandUpdate = "UPDATE [TransRecord] SET [Quantity] = @Quantity, [SubTotal] = @SubTotal, [Total] = @Total WHERE [ProductCode] = @ProductCode";

                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand(_commandUpdate, conn))
                    using (OleDbCommand _cmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(_commandSelect, conn))
                    using (OleDbCommand _cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand(commandUpdate, conn))
                    {
                        _cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        _cmdSelect.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCode;

                        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@SubTotal", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@SubTotal", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Total", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@Total", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                        using (OleDbDataReader dReader = _cmdSelect.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dReader.Read())
                            {
                                cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);

                                cmdUpdate.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCode;
                                cmdUpdate.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = quantity;
                                cmdUpdate.Parameters["@SubTotal"].Value = price;
                                cmdUpdate.Parameters["@Total"].Value = _price;

                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = productCode;
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = quantity;
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@SubTotal"].Value = price;
                                _cmdUpdate.Parameters["@Total"].Value = _price;

                                int numberOfRows = _cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                int _numberOfRows = cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                            dReader.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
        }

private void UpdatePrice(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numericTextBox1.TextLength >= 6)
            {
                decimal quantity = Convert.ToInt32(this.numericUpDown1.Value);
                decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
                int total = Convert.ToInt32(quantity * price);

                if (numericUpDown1.Value > 0)
                {
                    this.numericTextBox3.Text = total.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

The `Total` is working when it is not in the datagridview, it is in here (shown as screenshot):

[image]

But when it goes to the datagridview and when i change the `Quantity`, it does not update the `Total` based on `SubTotal * Quantity`

I appreciate your help and answer!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your datagridview is bound to your data. Are you making sure the grid is bound again with the updated data?

Comment: i am not so sure Mr Danexxtone. I am new in this matter though

Answer (score 0):

In order for the grid to update with the correct result, you need to do two things: the first is to update the Total in the dataset. The second is to rebind the grid to the updated dataset. The most common way to do that is to set the datasource to null and then back to your  dataset. I would also suggest to look at your sql statements, in particular cmdSelect. It's never used.
**Edit:**
Take a look at [EditMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode.aspx) and the [CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx) event. It should be good start to start editing the grid. The EditMode specifies when to edit the cell and the cellEndEdit event can be used to update the data in your grid.

Comment: ah yes, you are right Mr Danexxtone, i just review the code again, and i just realized, i just need one SELECT Statement to do the two UPDATE Statement. Thank you Danexxtone, i will update the posted code above.

Comment: You can update the grid with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7009131/571881

Comment: Sir, the link that you gave me is for refresh the datagridview right? What i want is when i edit the data through datagridview, it is not updating like at the textbox (before submit to the datagridview)