# Need to update dataGridView, Trying to update dataGridView, but no way

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

this is the code:

(tianDataSet is the Dataset created using the designer)
(roleBindingSource if the Binding Source created using the designer)
tianDataSet.country is the table of countries.

```
 roleBindingSource.DataSource = tianDataSet.country;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = roleBindingSource;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.Update();
```

It is refreshed but there is no rows there when it happened.

Can you help?

Comment: There is something like you have. You need using ResetBindings. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7079829/2050745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution for I want:

```
roleBindingSource.DataSource = roleTableAdapter.GetData();
dataGridView1.DataSource = roleBindingSource;
roleBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```