# Refresh a dataview grid in c#

Tags: c#, dataset, dataview

I have a form with a DataGridView item that views a table from my databse. Another form adds a new row to that table and closes it self. In the first form, at the closing event of the second form, i want the first form to update/refresh/refill itself to the new data just added.
I have tried this:

```
this.swimmersTableAdapter.Update(this.databaseDataSet1.swimmers);
```

And:

```
This.Update();
```

But unsuccessfully.

it does refresh it self when i stop debugging, and run it again, but ofcource it's not practical for the client/user.

any solutions ?

Comment: You could try the voted answer in this question;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need this...

**Form 1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1() 
    {
        //'add a label and a buttom to form
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
    }

    public void RefreshGrid() 
    {
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
}
```

**Form 2:**

```
public class Form2 : Form 
{
    Form1 _frm1;

    public Form2(Form1 frm1) 
    {
        _frm1 = frm1;
        this.FormClosing += Form2_FormClosing;
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
    {
        _frm1.RefreshGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specific if doing C# WPF or Winforms.

But as noted via the comment, you could just rebind the new source, or do

```
YourForm.YourGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

If the This.Update() in your code was within the datagrid you are referring, try

```
This.Items.Refresh();
```