# How should I refresh a Datagrid View with two Lists?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two lists:

```
public List<Line> UnfilteredList {get; private set;}
public List<Line> FilteredList {get {
                      return this.UnfilteredList.Where(x=> x.IsItem);
      }
}
```

I have the grid binding to the Filtered List. This is showing a list of the items being filtered. However, when I add an item to UnfilteredList, this doesn't show up on the grid because assumingly the databinding does not refresh.

What are the possible solutions to this and how do I notify the DataGrid View to re-bind to the list once an item has been changed/added/removed from the UnfilteredList?

The list is being bound by using

```
this.dgvMain.DataSource =new BindingList<Line>(FilteredList);
```

Comment: Rebind your data gridview using these techniques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-bind based on two scenarios:

A new list is created and when items are added/removed. Because of this, I would recommend using an ObservableColleciton to observe the adding/removing of items, and then you can force a re-bind whenever this happens.

```
private ObservableCollection<Line> _unfilteredList;
public ObservableCollection<Line> UnfilteredList 
{
    get { return _unfilteredList; }
    private set
    {
        _unfilteredList = value;
        UpdateList();
    }
}

private List<Line> _filteredList; 
public List<Line> FilteredList 
{
    get 
    {
        return _filteredList;
    }
    private set
    {
        _filteredList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void UpdateList()
{
    if (UnfilteredList != null)
    {
        FilteredList = null;
        FilteredList = UnfilteredList.Where(x=> x.IsItem).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then, you can call `UpdateList` when items are added/removed

```
// subscribe
UnfilteredList += OnCollectionChanged;

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.NewItems != null) || (e.OldItems != null))
    {
        UpdateList();
    }
}
```