# When add row at the end of datagridview bound to List the new row do not display after added row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` with `datagridviewbuttoncolumn`, I used the button to show search form for select data from another table. when user select data from search form I want to update current `datagridviewrow` with selected data:
[image]

when user select search button for first time `datagridview` row update correctly and a new row add at the end of rows:

[image]

but when select search button for second time the new row at the end do not appears.

How can I fix this problem?
is there better solution to do this?

```
private void dgvPlannedWoInstruction_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     var senderId = (DataGridView) sender;
     if (senderId.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
     {
        var frmSearch = new FrmStandardInstructionList();
        frmSearch.ShowDialog();
        if (frmSearch.ucStandardInstructionList1.standardInstructionDto != null)
        {
            senderId.BeginEdit(true);              
            PlannedInstructionDTO p;
            senderId.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            senderId.BeginEdit(true);
            senderId.CurrentRow.Cells["StandardInstructionCode"].Value = frmSearch.ucStandardInstructionList1.standardInstructionDto.Number;
            senderId.CurrentRow.Cells["StandardInstructionId"].Value = frmSearch.ucStandardInstructionList1.standardInstructionDto.Id;
            senderId.EndEdit();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: when you select a row, you want to show it as a new row at the end of GRID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refresh the DataSource after it has been updated like:

```
DataGridView view = new DataGridView();
view.DataSource = somesource;
view.DataSource = null;
view.DataSource = updatedsource;
```

Sorry I can't post comments, but this should help.
See also: [How can I refresh c# dataGridView after update ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update)