# Datagridview c# Where query

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am attempting to make my datagridview3 populate with the results of the following code and query but when I click the button to run the code the datagrid view stays blank. Is there anything I am missing?

```
                private void filter()
    {
        string Query2 = "Select * " +
            "From Child " +
            "WHERE @Value like '@Textbox'";

        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LT-SDGFLD-1803;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=");
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(Query2 , con2);
        try
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Value", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Textbox", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd2.Parameters["@Value"].Value = Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBox;
            cmd2.Parameters["@Textbox"].Value = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox;
            con2.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da2.SelectCommand = cmd2;
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dt2;
            dataGridView3.Update();
            dataGridView3.Refresh();
            con2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView3.DataSource = "LT-SDGFLD-1803";
        dataGridView3.Refresh();
        filter();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBox = comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I refresh c# dataGridView after update ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update)

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi Didn't work, still nothing populating in Datagridview3

Comment: did you check with the debugger, whether you `dt2` has any entries at all ?=!. Are the columns with their corresponding headers at least visible in the datagridview? or is it completely empty?

Comment: @MongZhu I know for definite that what I was inputting exists within my SQL database. I don't know how to view the debugger and see what it pulls back?

Comment: set a breakpoint at this line: `dataGridView3.DataSource = dt2;`. Run the program in Debug modus. -> it will stop at this line and let you examine the variables. Then hover with the mouse over the variable `dt2` and check the `Rows.Count` property

Comment: @MongZhu The rows count is 0 which I am guessing means that my values aren't being saved and set?
I have updated the OP with my latest code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154781/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-imamage597).

Comment: I am not sure if you can pass the field name `@Value` as a parameter. Try the query without parameters.

Comment: @Slai The query works perfectly if I manually input the data I want back.

Comment: one of the errors is that you need to use `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead of `omboBox1.SelectedText.ToString();`. otherwise the value of `Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBox` will be empty.

Comment: @MongZhu I have changed this to no avail. Still an empty Datagridview upon button press

Comment: @imamage597 I know. There is more, but I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: actually the next point is that you should use the value from combobox directly, since it is safe for sql injection. Parameters are used only for values that you want to compare, not for placeholders for column names

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `dataGridView3.DataBind();` after adding `datasource` to the `DataGridview`.

Comment: I have another datagridview which uses the same code as this but without the textbox and combobox and that works perfectly. The databind doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `DataBind()` on a `DataGridView` in `Winforms`? `DataBind()` applies to `GridView` in `asp.net WebForms`

Answer (score 0):

Field name can't be passed as parameter, but something like this should work:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Child WHERE " + Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBox + " LIKE '@Textbox'";
string cnStr = "Data Source=LT-SDGFLD-1803;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnStr)) {
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Textbox", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox;
    da.Fill(dt);
}
dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
```