# How to make datagridview reload on an edit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a problem with `dataGridView`. Its bound to Northwind database, `EntityFramework` code first, and have two forms, one for edit and insert new Employees and one for showing list of all and delete. When I try to edit, datagrid won't show the edited text, but when loaded again in form for edit it's edited. How to make `datagridview` to show edited text? Insert and delete works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I refresh c# dataGridView after update ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update)

Comment: No,I'l tried that,but not helped.