# Display Datagridview dynamically created chechboxvalue? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridviewcolumn

I want to check all/ only certain Checkboxes as checked.
I tried various versions from stackoverflow but none seem to work out.
The code is called directly after dynamically creating the datagrid as I only want to load the Data once. - Datagrid is created in my Form_Load
The value of the Checkboxes are changed but not displayed.

//This is how i create the Datagrid column - not question relevant

```
for (int kacnt = 1; kacnt <= Ei.Kaanzahl; kacnt++)
  {
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Kachk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    Kachk.HeaderText = "Kamera" + kacnt;
    Kachk.Width = 70;
    WarDataGridView.Columns.Add(Kachk);
  }
```

// The code I actually have problems with - the display of the value

```
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in WarDataGridView.Rows)
  {
    for (int col = 1; col < WarDataGridView.ColumnCount; col++)
    {
     (WarDataGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = true;}}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please consider posting a [MCVE] to reproduce the problem and describe the problem and expected result.

Comment: Can you also mention event or method, in which you are trying to update DataGridView source? You will need to refresh once datagridview source is being updated.. try following stackoverflow discussion,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update

Comment: What is the column index of the column you want to check? You are starting at index 1 which means you are skipping the first column (index 0).  Also, if your checkbox column is hidden, you need to use `WarDataGridView.Columns.Count` in your for loop.  `WarDataGridView.ColumnCount` only returns displayed columns.

Comment: Edited the above things.. I only want to check displayed columns and yes i am skipping the first column intentionally since it is a Text Column.. Thanks a lot tho

Comment: Are you using a datasource, i.e. `WarDataGridView.DataSource = dataSource_dataTable`?  I've noticed the data isn't finished loading immediately after databinding.  In that case you need a `WarDataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event, and set the columns from there.  You also may need to set the particular column with `Kamerachk.TrueValue = true` and `Kamerachk .FalseValue = false`

Comment: am not using a Datasource but will try that out. Thanks a lot

Comment: It worked out!! Thank you a lot - would love to mark your answer it as THE answer.

Comment: I'll post as an answer... Just click the check mark to accept as the answer. You can upvote the comment as well if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your columns' True and False values like so:

`Kamerachk.TrueValue = true;`
and
`Kamerachk.TrueValue = false;`