# System.InvalidOperationException: rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's rows collection when the control is data-bound

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, addition, windows-forms-designer

I have a datagridview which I fill with a txt file which have 7 columns and 20 rows by default.

I want to add new rows to my datagridview using a button and textboxes in two different form, form1 for open form2 which contains the textboxes and the "ADD" button.

But I always got an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's rows collection when the control is data bound

What can I do?

I have tried

```
form1.datagridview.add(textbox1.text,textbox2.text...etc.)
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using data binding to bind your values to the `DataGridView`, instead of adding the row to the control itself you will have to add the new value to the actual list that the `DataGridView` is bound to.

There is only one problem with that: Just adding the value to the data source will not refresh the `DataGridView` so you will not see it in the UI.

So what you actually want to do is using a `BindingSource`.
The `BindingSource` is bound to the `DataGridView.DataSource` and also has a `DataSource`-Property itself wich is your actual list of values.

Here is a small example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingSource _dataSource;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            
        _dataSource = new BindingSource();
        _dataSource.DataSource = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "User1", Age = 1 },
            new Person { Name = "User2", Age = 2 },
        };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = _dataSource;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataSource.Add(new Person { Name = "User3", Age = 3 });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

(`dataGridView1` was created by dragging-and-dropping it from the toolbox to the form so the properties all have default values)

I used this question as a reference for this answer:
[How can I refresh c# dataGridView after update ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update)