# LINQ query is not retrieving saved data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datagridview

maybe I need to start over. Thx for the helpful links for the datagridview but I didn't really need to bring that up.

The essence of the problem is this: I use this method for 2 things:
- to get the necessary data out of the database when adding a new record
- to get the necessary data out of the database after I've updated a record

```
public void refreshReservationDetail()
{
    _oReservationDetail = (from rd in _oReservation.tblReservationDetails
                           where rd.ReservationID == _oReservationObject.ID
                           select rd).ToList();
}
```

When I add a new record the new data is saved and loaded into the datagridview. So this works fine.

When I update an existing record (that is already shown in the datagridview) the altered content is also being saved properly but the method above is not giving me the saved data but still the old data. How come?

Here I save my data

```
//frmReservationDetail
public event dRefresh SavedActivity;

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.ReservationID = _oReservationDetail.ReservationObjectData.ID;
    _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(_oReservationDetail.ReservationObjectData.StartTime.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + _oDateTime[cboStartTime.getSelectedID()]);
    _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(_oReservationDetail.ReservationObjectData.StartTime.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + _oDateTime[cboEndTime.getSelectedID()]);
    if (this.cboLanguage.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.LanguageID = this.cboLanguage.getSelectedID();
    }
    else
        _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.LanguageID = null;

    if (this.cboTargetgroup.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.TargetgroupID = this.cboTargetgroup.getSelectedID();
    }
    else
        _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.TargetgroupID = null;

    if (this.cboExcursion.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.ExcursionID = this.cboExcursion.getSelectedID();
    }
    else
        _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.ExcursionID = null;

    _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.Participants = int.Parse(this.txtParticipants.Text);
    _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.Leaders = int.Parse(this.txtLeaders.Text);
    _oReservationDetail.ReservationDetailData.Remarks = this.txtRemarks.Text;
    _oReservationDetail.save();

    if(SavedActivity != null)
        SavedActivity();

    this.Close();
    }

//clsReservationDetail
public void save()
{
    int i = _oReservationDetail.ID;
    if (_oReservationDetail.ID == 0)
    {
            _oReservation.tblReservationDetails.InsertOnSubmit(_oReservationDetail);
            _oReservation.SubmitChanges();
    }
    _oReservation.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: You need to refresh the grid after row update

Comment: This should be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253843/simple-datagridview-refresh-question

Comment: Have you called `refreshReservationDetail()`
method after updating/inserting the data???

Comment: Could you please show the code where you save your updates?

Comment: The problem is not the saving. There I am sure it works just fine. I just wonder why the the data in _oReservationDetail is not getting refreshed although I ask for the query to run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't rebinding your datagridview. After you save/update you should be calling `refreshReservationDetail()` again, and then you'll need to once again set the datasource to that variable and rebind it. If you are doing this asynchronously with an update panel or some such, you'll have to call `refreshReservationDetail()` at the end of the event that is fired for saving/updating. If the page is posting back normally then just make sure your databinding to the gridview occurs regardless if it's a postback or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded by calling this loop:

```
foreach (var oReservationDetail in
    _oReservationObject.ReservationData.tblReservationDetails)
```

I have used the setted relations in the database instead of querying again to get the data. It now works!