# Refresh datagridview win forms after updating the database from a child form

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, dataadapter

how to refresh datagridview after making changes on the database from another form, 
after closing child form i tried to refresh the datagridview with click event but it's not working, do i have to use dataset ?

```
            //create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
            dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(gQuery, connString);

            //create a command builder
            cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

            //create a DataTable to hold the query results
            dTable = new DataTable();

            //fill the DataTable
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);


            //BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
            bSource = new BindingSource();

            //set the BindingSource DataSource
            bSource.DataSource = dTable;


            //set the DataGridView DataSource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

    private void button_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();


    }
```

Help me, please thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple DataGridView refresh question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253843/simple-datagridview-refresh-question)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790676/why-does-my-datagridview-refuse-to-refresh/9791331#9791331

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
dataGridView1.Update();
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

When you link your database with "DataSource" in DataGridView properties, IDE automatically adds BindingSource and TableAdapter to your form.

If database is updated and you want to refresh DataGridView, call this:

```
this.<table name>TableAdapter.Fill(this.<DB name>DataSet.<table name>);
```

Where `<table name>` is name of your table (for example Users) and `<DB name>` is name of your database (for example MyDB).

```
this.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDBDataSet.Users);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 bSource.DataSource = dTable;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

it would be better if you will recall your table