# How to refresh or show immediately in datagridview after inserting?

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, insert, refresh

After entering data into all the textbox, and after clicking the submit button, it won't immediately show in the datagridview, I need to reopen the form in order to see the new inserted row. What code to put in for refresh?

Followed @user3222297 code. by adding grdPatient.Update(); and grdPatient.Refresh(); still doesn't get refreshed after i click the OK for insert successful.

[image: doesn't get refresh]

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class patient : Form
    {
        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Patient = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter PatientAdapter;

        public patient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnSubmit.Text == "Clear")
            {
                btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";

                txtpFirstName.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
               btnSubmit.Text = "Clear";
            int result = AddPatientRecord();
            if (result > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insert Successful");
                grdPatient.Update(); 
                grdPatient.Refresh();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Insert Fail");

            }
        }
        private int AddPatientRecord()
        {
            int result = 0;
            // TO DO: Codes to insert customer record
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            String strCommandText = "INSERT PATIENT(pFirstName, pLastName, pContact, pAddress, pCity, pZip, pNationality, pRace, pIC, pGender, pDOB, pBloodType, pEmail) "
                + " VALUES (@pFirstName,@pLastName,@pContact,@pAddress,@pCity,@pZip,@pNationality, @pRace, @pIC, @pGender, @pDOB, @pBloodType, @pEmail)";

            SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", txtpFirstName.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLastName", txtpLastName.Text);
            //updateCmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pContact", txtpContact.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pAddress", txtpAddress.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCity", txtpCity.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pZip", txtpZip.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNationality", txtpNationality.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pRace", txtpRace.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtpIC.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pGender", txtpGender.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDOB", txtpDOB.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", txtpBloodType.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pEmail", txtpEmail.Text);
            // STEP 3 open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
            myConnect.Open();
            // STEP 4: execute command
            // indicates number of record updated.
            result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // STEP 5: Close
            myConnect.Close();
            return result;

        }

        private void patient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPatientRecords();
        }

        private void LoadPatientRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT pFirstName, pLastName, pContact, pAddress, pCity, pZip, pNationality, pRace, pIC, pGender, pDOB, pBloodType, pEmail, pUsername, pPassword FROM Patient";

            PatientAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(PatientAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Patient.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            PatientAdapter.Fill(Patient);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Patient.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdPatient.DataSource = Patient;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please put only usefull code related to question don't  write all of your code

Comment: Did you try calling grdPatient.DataBind() after setting the DataSource?

Comment: Where is my code of setting the DataSource? @Karthik Kalyanasundaram

Comment: My teacher gave me the practical codes, that doesn't refresh the datagridview after inserting!!.  @Karthik Kalyanasundaram

Comment: `grdPatient.DataSource = Patient;` is the line which sets DataSource. In `if` block add this line too `grdPatient.DataBind()`

Comment: Like this? if (Patient.Rows.Count > 0) grdPatient.DataSource = Patient; grdPatient.DataBind(); I got error. Error 2 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @Karthik Kalyanasundaram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LoadPatientRecords()` after a successful insertion.

Try the below code

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (btnSubmit.Text == "Clear")
        {
            btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";

            txtpFirstName.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
           btnSubmit.Text = "Clear";
           int result = AddPatientRecord();
           if (result > 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Insert Successful");

               LoadPatientRecords();
           }
           else
               MessageBox.Show("Insert Fail");
         }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Only need to fill datagrid again like this:

```
this.XXXTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.XXX);
```

If you use automaticlly connect from dataGridView this code create automaticlly in Form_Load()

Comment: Yours is a simple way of doing it if we are automatically connecting from DataGridView. I used your suggestion since I am automatically connecting.

Answer (score 9):

Try refreshing the datagrid after each insert

```
datagridview1.update();
datagridview1.refresh();
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: u mean after each updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue line. I put that code? will try that after u get home thanks @user3222297

Comment: You can give that after calling the function AddPatientRecord(). Or give it when you give "Insert Succesfull".

Comment: I added a new image. Is this how I do it? but I got error. @user3222297

Comment: Kindly put the statements inside if loop in { } and then try it.
Like this : if(result>0)
{
Messagebox.Show("...");
datagridview1.update();
datagridview1.refresh();  
}

Comment: I have no errors already by following your code. I edited my codes above on my post and added a image. But the datagrid still doesn't refresh after I insert a record. I still need to reopen the form. @user3222297

Comment: Even after clicking the ok button of Insert Successful its not refreshing the grid?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `datagridview` `DataSource` to `null` and rebind it again.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myAccesscon.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    dataGridView.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView.Update();
    dataGridView.Refresh();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, myAccesscon);
    myAccesscon.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable bookings = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(bookings);
    dataGridView.DataSource = bookings;
    myAccesscon.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolved your problem, but a simple way to resolve this is rebuilding the DataSource (it is a property) of your datagridview. For example:

```html
grdPatient.DataSource = MethodThatReturnList();
```

So, in that MethodThatReturnList() you can build a List (List is a class) with all the items you need. In my case, I have a method that return the values for two columns that I have on my datagridview.

Pasch.

Answer (score 0):

In the form designer add a new timer using the toolbox. In properties set "Enabled" equal to "True".

[image]

The set the `DataGridView` to equal your new data in the timer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this.donorsTableAdapter.Fill(this.sbmsDataSet.donors);

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything mentionned here and it all failed.
What I needed to do was `Thread.Sleep(1_000);` between the database update and the datagridview refresh.
It seems that the datagridview was refreshing before the data was updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and call the data table method method in that. Below is the example:

```
private void RefreshDataGridView() { 

    usrlogin = Application.OpenForms.OfType().FirstOrDefault();     
    con.ConnectionString = usrlogin.connectionString;
    DataTable data = loadinGrid(); // Assuming this method fetches data from your database

    // Clear existing rows and add the new data
    customDataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        string usrn = row["username"].ToString();
        string usrid = row["userid"].ToString();
        string role = "";

        switch (usrid)
        {
            case "1":
                role = "Admin";
                break;
            case "2":
                role = "Operator";
                break;
            case "3":
                role = "Authorizer";
                break;
            case "4":
                role = "Key Officer";
                break;
            default:
                role = "Unknown";
                break;
        }
        customDataGridView2.Rows.Add(false, usrn, role, usrid); // Add checkboxes, username, and userid
    }
    customDataGridView2.CellClick += customDataGridView2_CellContentClick_1;
    customDataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below piece of code.

```
this.dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
```