# Dynamically adding row in Datagrid Based on Textbox's data

Tags: c#, dynamic, datagrid, textbox

I want to add row in my datagrid based on data that i fill in textbox. the display from page is just like this.

[image: image 1]

How can I possible to add row of datagrid based on data that i fill to textbox dynamically?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting

try something like this.

Comment: Thanks xxmrlnxx, but the one I'm looking for is whenever i put data in my textbox, it's automatically adding into datagrid, without any button or else. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Using textchanged event.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/textchanged

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PopulateGrid(textBox1.Text);
}
void PopulateGrid(string queryStr)
{
  dataGridView1.DataSource = _journal.GetSearchResults(queryStr);
  SetStatus(dataGridView1.Rows.Count); // Change status bar (not shown)
}
```

You can substitute the _journal.GetSearchResults(querystr) to just adding a datarow to a datatable then binding to the datasource.  You should get the general concept.