# Master-Detail Gridview Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, master-detail

I have a Master Grid and Detail Grid, Detail Grid allows me to UPDATE and DELETE but it is not refreshing. If I Update twice or Delete twice it is deleting or else when I expand the Master Grid the Updated data are shown in the Detail Grid. I am using CallBackPanel here. How can I refresh the Detail Grid?

```
<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="CallbackPanel"
 ClientInstanceName="CallbackPanel" OnCallback="CallbackPanel_Callback">

    <PanelCollection>

        <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent3" runat="server">

            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdMasterBuilding"
                ClientInstanceName="grdMasterBuilding" 
                runat="server" KeyFieldName="BuildingId" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
                        FieldName="Name" Caption="Building Name"/>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn                             
                        FieldName="Description" Caption="Building Description">
                </Columns>

                <Templates>
                    <DetailRow>

                        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdDetailBuilding" 
                            ClientInstanceName="grdDetailBuilding" runat="server" 
                            KeyFieldName="FloorId" AutoGenerateColumns="False"

                            <Columns>
                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn   
                                    FieldName="FloorCode" Caption="Floor Code">
                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn> 

                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
                                    FieldName="FloorLength" Caption="Floor Width" />
                                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
                                    FieldName="FloorHeight" Caption="Floor" />
                                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                                <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn
                                    FieldName="FloorType" Caption="Floor Type" />
                                </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

                                <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn
                                    FieldName="DeliveryOption" VisibleIndex="9" 
                                    Caption="Delivery Option" />
                                </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn
                                    FieldName="NumbersOfUnits" Caption="No Of Units"
                                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn
                                    FieldName="SquareFeet" Caption="Square Feet" 
                                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>        
                            </Columns> 

                        </dx:ASPxGridView>

                    </DetailRow>
                </Templates>

                <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="true" />

            </dx:ASPxGridView>
        </dx:PanelContent>
    </PanelCollection>
```

Comment: adding too much code, won't attract. be specific

Comment: not my specialty. but you can start bounty. that will help you.

Comment: please view this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting) it solve the problem you are looking for

Comment: Note your master grid  FieldName="Description" lacks /> in the end, and the detail grid definition line lacks > in the end too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3578 .

Basically the idea is that you need to process the EndCallback client side event of the detail grid and update master grid using ClientInstanceName: grdMasterBuilding.Refresh() .

So you have to add the following line to the detail grid markup before the <Columns> element:

```
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback" BeginCallback="OnBeginCallback"/>
```

then add these JS OnBeginCallback and OnEndCallback methods like in the mentioned example only that in OnEndCallback you will use your master grid ClientInstanceName to refresh it.

```
function OnEndCallback(s, e) {
   if ((command == "ADDNEWROW" || command == "UPDATEEDIT") && !s.isError) {
      grdMasterBuilding.Refresh();
   }
}
```

If you don't need to update master grid upon child edit/delete, try refreshing only the child grid in the same way, by using grdDetailBuilding.Refresh() . Note, the example saves the action command name during OnBeginCallback and then checks if the command was ADDNEWROW or UPDATEEDIT. You may need to add the check for the delete action. I'm not sure if UPDATEEDIT will be called for row deletion, maybe there is a separate command for that. You can know that by using browser developer tools and stopping at breakpoint in the OnBeginCallback.

HTH