# How to create "Refresh" button for datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

My problem is, when I create a button that refreshes data grid when the new auction or delete auction is clicked, nothing happens at all, or even some syntax error shows up. So I need:

Refresh button, which I made through `XAML`.
So when the delete button is clicked I need a row deleted, that I made too.
But, my refresh doesn't work. I need to log out from the application and log in again, to make some changes. I don't really know how to do this.

I'll provide some pictures down below, and also some code.

Default log in: 
[image: 1]

Adding a sale or deleting a sale, then logging out and logging back in:
[image: 2]

I tried making a data grid that auto-updates. I tried making this button, I got a few syntax errors, I also tried adding `dgGridView.Items.Refresh()`, didn't help either.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindDataGrid();
        }


        private void BindDataGrid()
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AuctionTbl2", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            da.Fill(ds);
            dgGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            dgGrid.Items.Refresh();

        }

        private void LogoutBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindowGuest mwg = new MainWindowGuest();
            mwg.Show();
            this.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("You have been logged out.");
        }

        private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = 
              ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
                conn.Open();

                string query = "delete from AuctionTbl2";
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Deleted");

                conn.Close();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void AddNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewDeleteWindow newDeleteWindow = new NewDeleteWindow();
            newDeleteWindow.DataContext = new NewSaveButton();
            newDeleteWindow.ShowDialog();

        }
    }

}
```

I expect to make a refreshment when the sale is added or deleted, on a refresh button or without it, doesn't matter. Just to refresh this grid. Thank you all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting

Comment: what are you deleting ? "delete from tblAuction" it'll not delete a record.

Comment: Where is the code for Refresh button?

Comment: @ZainArshad I'm a beginner, I don't know so much. I'm trying to experiment this. It deletes it in some way. When I press the "delete button", it somehow deletes it from a database I don't know what should I get? Btw, I removed Refresh button, I thought it couldn't help me anyways.

Comment: Refresh the data, datasource or query not the control.  But you are missing rags indicating the technology used to be much help.

Comment: Run my code, it works?

Comment: If you dont stick to MVVM or a databinding, you would need to do manually the grid refreshing when its data changes. Call you refresh code after a CRUD operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the `table`, just like you update t when you load the `form`. Replace these methods in your code:

```
private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
        conn.Open();

        string query = "delete from AuctionTbl2";  // i think you are not aaully deleting the record you want to delete
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
        conn.Close();
        BindDataGrid();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

 private void AddNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewDeleteWindow newDeleteWindow = new NewDeleteWindow();
    newDeleteWindow.DataContext = new NewSaveButton();
    newDeleteWindow.ShowDialog();
    BindDataGrid();
}
```

**UPDATE:** For deleting the `sale` that you have clicked on follow these steps:

- make a `global variable` "int IDdelete".
- Go to the `Designer.cs`.
- Click on the `dataGridView`.
- You will see `Properties` on right side.
- click on `events`.
- Scroll and find `CellClick` and double-click on it.
- It will make a method named like this `private void dgGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`
- Now paste the paste the code below in that method.

```
private void dgGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   IDdelete = Convert.InTo32(dgGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
}

Now, in your `SQL query` use this query.

   "DELETE from AuctionTbl2 where id=@IDelete";
```

Comment: Yes man, this works. For adding at least. When I select one row and delete it, it deletes all rows?

Comment: What it delete all records ? Thats what i have mention in comment in the code

Comment: you have to make some changes get the `Id` of the selected row then use a `Where` clause

Comment: I included where clause for id like this: "delete from AuctionTbl2 where id=@Id". It says that I need to declare a scalar variable? Sorry guys, I really don't know, I appreciate the time you take for explaining me.

Comment: See you have to make a variable `IDdelete` and make a `event` that when you click on a record then the `ID` of the record get saved in the `IDdelete` variable and the give that `IDdelete` to the `where clause. You understood ?

Comment: @ZainArshad You mean like I need private field for id, property and constructor? One more question. Is it better to start a new project or to try to fix this one?

Comment: Wait I am updating my answer follow those instructions and you'll get what you want, If it helps you then do mark it as "answer" and "upvote" it .. wait a moment :)

Comment: @ZainArshad I see only CellEditEnding? I'm using WPF application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191550/discussion-between-xvenum-dll-and-zain-arshad).

Answer (score 0):

Try this after `Add` and `delete` blocks.

```
DataTable dt = dal.select();
dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

If not resolve, ping me on **skype:** vipinweb2