# C# Datagridview refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

This is all of the code regarding my DataGridView. Is there anything that could cause Refresh() not to work?

```
    this.usersDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.usersDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.usersDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    this.usersDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.usersDataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
    this.iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
    this.uSERNAMEDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
    this.nAMEDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
    this.sURNAMEDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
    this.pASSWORDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
    this.pERMISSIONDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
    this.usersDataGridView.DataSource = this.usersBindingSource1;
    this.usersDataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9);
    this.usersDataGridView.Name = "usersDataGridView";
    this.usersDataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
    this.usersDataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(488, 291);
    this.usersDataGridView.TabIndex = 0;
    this.usersDataGridView.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.usersdataGridView_RowClick);
```

I apologize in advance if this question has been answered, but I could not find answer that could help me.

Comment: What is not refreshing ? Did you try to refresh your binding source ?

Comment: usersDataGridView.Refresh(); is not working. I tried to refresh binding source, still not working

Comment: Try this maybe : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253843/simple-datagridview-refresh-question?rq=1)

Comment: as I see this (correct me if i'am wrong), this example works if my data source is list type. My data source is dataset, which is more logical by my opinion

Comment: I was meaning : `this.usersDataGridView.DataSource = null; this.usersDataGridView.DataSource = this.usersBindingSource1;`

Comment: tried that before, no result...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(DataSet); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = this.usersBindingSource1;
```